# Publishing Geoprocessing Service to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service

I have set up a one Organization site in the ArcGIS.com, where I have published my data and also consumed data from ArcGIS Online.

I have a workflow that creates a buffer from a point feature class, and now I want to publish my workflow as a geoprocessing service in ArcGIS Online.

How can I publish to ArcGIS Online and share to other users so that they can consume this geoprocessing service?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. Your question is very short and asks something that is readily available via a Google Search. To avoid having your question closed, you need to add some information about what research you have done and what specific problem you are experiencing. If you do not, it is highly likely that your question will be closed.

Answer (score 6):

You can't publish a geoprocessing service directly to ArcGIS Online. In other words, Esri's servers won't host your geoprocessing service for you and provide the processing power. You need to publish the service to ArcGIS Server, which gives you a REST URL to access the service.

With a geoprocessing serice, all you can do in ArcGIS Online is share that REST URL to potential users by adding a new item to your content (under My Content click "Add Item", select "From the Web" and then use the REST URL as a "ArcGIS Server web service").